# Está expirando o tempo dos Cookies criados quando fecho o navegador

Tags: php, cookies

Estou aqui perguntando porque infelizmente já tentei todas as alternativas em pesquisas desde semana passada. E provavelmente estou fazendo alguma coisa errada.

Vamos lá:

```
    setcookie("email", "email", time() + (360 * 24 * 3600));
```

Este é o código que eu criei o cookie. Que fica no cabeçalho antes de ler o html.
Para que o cookie dure 1 ano.

Porém, no outro dia ele insere este cookie denovo. Faço uma verificação para ver se ele existe e depois insiro o registro no banco de dados, para ter controle:

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['email'])){

    setcookie("email", "email", time() + (360 * 24 * 3600));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO db(id, email, data) VALUES (0, 'email', NOW() )")

    }
```

Não sei o motivo do erro. Talvez tenha que configurar o php.ini, ou alguma outra coisa. Porém já pesquisei e não encontrei o erro. É a primeira vez que trabalho com cookies.

Quem puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Comment: O erro não pode estar na inserção no banco? Se o campo `id` for uma chave primaria ele não irá conseguir adicionar o registro.

Comment: Não @gmsantos, na verdade está sendo inseridos vários registros. Isso não deveria ocorrer, uma vez que o cookie "deveria" durar 1 ano.

Comment: O que eu preciso, é que se o usuário desligar o seu computador, no outro dia eu recupero o mesmo cookie. Só isso. E registro os novos usuários que estão entrando no site.

Comment: Como o cookie fica dentro do browser, não deve ser nenhuma configuração do PHP. Existe a possibilidade também do seu browser não estar aceitando cookies ou eles serem limpos na hora que você reinicia a maquina.

Comment: Abra o console e veja a data de expiração do cookie no seu navegador. @gmsantos pode ter razão, na dúvida, use outro navegador para ver se não é a configuração.

Comment: Entao, fiz o teste mas nao é isso.

Comment: Testou em outro navegador e o console mostrou a data de expiração para *2016*?

Comment: Achei o problema.

Answer (score 1):

No setcookie exite um campo chamado `path`.

```
setcookie("email", "email", time() + (360 * 24 * 3600), '/');
//                                                       ^ path
```

aquela barra é aonde fica o local `path`, e indica aonde ele pode ser resgatado.

**path**

> O caminho no servidor aonde o cookie estará disponível. Se configurado para '/', o            cookie estará dosponível para todo o domain. Se configurado para o diretório '/foo/', o cookie estará disponível apenas dentro do diretório /foo/ e todos os subdiretórios como /foo/bar do domain. O valor padrão é o diretório atual onde o cookie está sendo configurado.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php

Quando você não indica o path do cookie, ele fica disponível até o navegador ser fechado. Não importa se é 1 ano. Se não for indicado o caminho, assim que o navegador fechar ele será deletado.

Além do mais, você pode indicar o domínio no qual quer que ele seja resgatado:

```
setcookie("email", "email", time() + (360 * 24 * 3600), '/', 'www.site.com.br');
```

**domain**

> O domínio para qual o cookie estará disponível. Configurando o domínio para 'www.example.com' fará com que o cookie esteja disponível no subdomínio www e nos subdomínios superiores. Cookies disponíveis para um domínio inferior, como 'example.com' estarão disponíveis para subdomínios superiores, como 'www.example.com'. Browsers antigos ainda implementam a » RFC 2109 e podem requerer um . no início para funcionar com todos os subdomínios.

Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram nos comentários.